# first-child doesn't work in tbody?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first td.is-active inside my tbody. The .is-active style is well accepted, but it's impossible to add a radius to the first (and only first) .is-active.

[Full code here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZpwmq)

Or just my SCSS:

```
td {
      &.is-active {
            background-color: $color5;

            &:first-child {
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        }
       }
}
```

An idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 1):

CSS properties are not cumulative and do not support sub-selection. `td.is-active:first-child` will *not* select the first element within the `.is-active` group. It will select the first td if it has the `.is-active` class, and no `td` matches this condition.

`td:first-child` will always select the first `td`, regardless of its class.

You are looking for the [`:first-of-class` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class), which, unfortunately, doesn't exist.